# Добавление мест для отображения виджетовWordpress.

Tags: wordpress, виджет

В тему нужно встроить дополнить виджеты. В интернете нашел, что нужно дописать functions.php Как-то так:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Правая колонка',
'before_widget' => '<div class="neobhodimui-klass">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
'after_title' => '</div>',
));
```

А в место, где должен отображаться виджет такое:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Правая колонка') ) { ?>
```

Не работает! Пожалуйста, объясните правильное встраивание мест для виджетов в WORDPRESS.

Comment: @Никита Кузнецов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я вижу тут не задаётся id для создаваемой области виджетов (кстати задавать такие вещи лучше латиницей), только имя. К тому-же на сколько я понимаю регистрировать садбар нужно не абы когда, а во время инициализации виджетов.

Читайте [кодекс](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), а не бложики, в кодексе инфа достовернее и полнее. Есть переводы кодекса на русский, если с языком Шекспира никак. По запросу `wordpress register_sidebar` нашлось аж два сайта с русскими переводами кодекса.